# How would I set an objective to 0 in 1.11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I set an objective to 0 using the scoreboard command if it is possible?

My command so far is:

```
/scoreboard objectives
```

But when I press tab after that it shows a list of what could be there, saying *"add, list, remove, setdisplay"* but it doesn't say set.

I know I have done this in one of my other maps but they were in 1.8 and I'm using 1.11 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing **objectives** and **players**. A scoreboard is not a value, or a variable. It cannot store a number. What you really want to do is set the value of a player on the scoreboard.

```
/scoreboard players set [player] [objective] [value]
```

For example:

```
/scoreboard players set @p locations 1
```